# Convert Integer in Hex String Notation into a signed 8-Bit Integer

Tags: ruby, integer, hex

I'd like to convert a hex string into an 8-bit **signed** integer, as shown in the following example:

```
irb> "0xff".unpack(X)
=> [-1]
```

The correct value for **X** is missing.

By reding https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-unpack and experimenting I do not find the correct value for **X**.

---

I could code that myself, like also posted here: https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/138200#615299 but I am convinced, there is a more elegant concise ruby way.

```
irb> length = 8
irb> mid = 2**(length-1)
irb> max_unsigned = 2**length
irb> to_signed = proc {|n| (n>=mid) ? n - max_unsigned : n}
irb> to_signed["0xFF".to_i(16)]
=> -1
```

---

Note: For the ***un***singed case, this is easy:

```
irb> "e0".hex
=> 224
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `c` directive comes very close but it expects a different input: a single character representing the signed 8-bit integer. This requires the input `"0xff"` to be `"\xff"`. So this conversion must take place first. At least one method known by you can be used here; the other one is [`Integer#chr`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Integer.html#method-i-chr):

```
"0xff".hex.chr # => "\xFF"
```

And the complete solution:

```
"0xff".hex.chr.unpack1(?c) # => -1
```